# Como reabrir um pedido que foi cancelado

Tags: magento

Queria saber como desfazer o cancelamento de um pedido na API do Magento 1.9, se alguém tiver uma ideia, agradeço ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente por padrão não existe uma rota na API para "desfazer" um cancelamento de pedido no Magento, mas é possível criar rotas customizadas, então você pode criar sua rota para desfazer um cancelamento. Na [documentação](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html) você pode verificar como criar suas rotas customizadas.